# Character/font rendering in chromium-browser

Tags: fonts, chromium

[buggy font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBRwv.png), [correct font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByktT.png), [more buggy font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Ka5.png)

I've been building some single purpose kiosks using Ubuntu server on RaspberyPis (models 3 and 4).  It's a minimal build that uses matchbox-window-manager and chromium in kiosk mode.

Prior to 22.04 we had no issues (see 'correct font' link). Building new Pi images from a base 22.04 install I'm encountering these font issues.

My process is pretty simple.  We use the RaspberryPi Imager to create the base install, then update && upgrade.  After that we have some scripts to install our packages and some configurations files to auto login and run our xinit script at the end of .bashrc to open the webpage.

Everything is working fine except for this issue with the font.  From what I can tell the specific font in the css of the webpage is not installed, but sans-serif is the fallback in the css code and that appears to be used, but it is just rendering wierd.

Looking for similar issues online I have tried to refresh the font cache but not much else comes up.

I've managed to install chrome (proper) from the debian stable repository and have no issues. This is not an ideal workaround due to other issues that will surely arise.

Comment: Hey you can file a bug with `ubuntu-bug chromium`.

Comment: sure... thanks for the suggestion (how/where exactly would I do that?)

Comment: You just open a terminal and type it.

Comment: I've submitted the bug, thanks!